# Style subtitle of ListItem of React Native Elements below avatar

Tags: react-native, flexbox

I would like to style my ListItem so that the subtitle is a block below the avatar and title. Like so:

[image]
Currently the subtitle is to the right of the avatar, this seems to be the default styling of ListItems.

[image: Default layout of List Items]

My code:

```js
  renderItems = (item) => {
    return <ListItem
      containerStyle={styles.listItem}
      title={item.data.title}
      avatar={{uri:item.data.thumbnail}}
      subtitle={
        <View style={styles.subtitle}>
          <Text>{item.data.author}</Text>
          <Text>{item.data.score}</Text>
          <Text>{item.data.num_comments}</Text>
        </View>
      }
    />
  }
  
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  listItem: {
    display: 'flex',
  },
  subtitle: {
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'space-around',
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there isn't one.

However as a workaround you can use `containerStyle` to make each list item high enough to contain your initial design and use `position: 'absolute', bottom: 0, left: 0, right: 0` on `subtitleStyle` to lock your subtitle in place.